# How to invoke GetService from program.cs or bindings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I currently have my `ISecretManager` class dependency injected. I use this class to grab secrets stored in AWS.

I can use secrets to create more dependency injections

```
Services.AddScoped<IDbContext>(
    x => new DbContext(
        Context.Configuration,
        x.GetService<ISecretManager>().Get("DB")))
```

Now I am in a predicament. I need to enable Redis cache but the value is stored in secrets.

```
Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
    //secret value goes here
    options.Configuration = // GetService<ISecretManager>().Get("REDIS")
});
```

How do I get `ISecretManager` service invoke so I can populate Redis connection string? Can I also implement this in program.cs of my ASP.NET Core webapp?

Comment: `builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(...)` or `builder.Configuration["Section:Secret"]` is you actually use .NET's User Secrets

Comment: Please show how you configure your `ISecretManager` and show its constructor. Preferable, make your question in a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please post the complete code. It's unclear whether you use a Minimal API or an old-style Startup class. In all of them you can access configuration settings. Instead of a custom `ISecretManager` that retrieves protected configuration settings you could use a different Configuration source to provide those configuration settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var value = Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ISecretManager>().Get("REDIS");
Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options => {
    options.Configuration = value;
});
```